# How to save or download PrimeNg chart images - Angular 4

Tags: html, angular, typescript, primeng

I'm using **PrimeNg** **chart** module (p-chart) to display charts inside cards. The requirement is, we should be able to save the images (of the charts/graphs) by clicking an download icon. I have used *ngFor* to iterate over an *JSON* object and have displayed the chart inside card successfully.

Here is the HTML:

```
...
<div class="card-media-block" id="Chart-{{rCard.id}}">
    <p-chart [type]="rCard.typeofReport" [data]="rCard.content"></p-chart>
</div>
...
```

I also found that ***p-chart*** is converted to ***canvas*** in runtime and thus doesn't have any dedicated *ID*. So I've used nearest *DIV* element's *ID* to reach to that canvas element using ***.childNodes*** property, but unfortunately not able to save/download the image from this.

Here is the runtime html generated from the above block (found by inspecting element):

```
<div _ngcontent-c3="" class="card-media-description" id="Chart-ReportCard1">
    <p-chart _ngcontent-c3="" class="ng-tns-c3-2" ng-reflect-type="bar" ng-reflect-data="[object Object]">
        <div>
            <iframe class="chartjs-hidden-iframe" tabindex="-1" style="display: block; overflow: hidden; border: 0px; margin: 0px; top: 0px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; height: 100%; width: 100%; position: absolute; pointer-events: none; z-index: -1;"></iframe>
            <canvas width="300" height="150" style="display: block;"></canvas>
        </div>
    </p-chart>
</div>
```

Here is the typescript function I tried to write for saving image:

```
saveImage(pCard): void {
    let chartDiv = document.getElementById('Chart-' + pCard['id']);
    let canvasElement = chartDiv.childNodes[1].childNodes[1].childNodes[2];

    console.log(canvasElement); // Output:- <canvas width="300" height="150" style="display: block;"></canvas>
    let imageURL = canvasElement.toDataURL(); // Error:- Property 'toDataURL' does not exist on type 'Node'.
    window.location.href = imageURL;
}
```

I'm stuck with this problem, kindly help.

Comment: Do anyone have any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Look into using the @ViewChildren decorator with QueryList and ElementRef to iterate through the elements

Example:
inside your template:

```
<div *ngFor="let cdl of chartDataList">
    <p-chart #barChart type="bar" [data]="cdl"></p-chart>
</div>
```

inside your component:

```
@ViewChildren("barChart") charts: QueryList<ElementRef>;

saveImage(event) {
    this.charts.forEach(element => {
        console.log(element);
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi @BillF, I've tried the above solution. In console.log I can see => UIChart {el: ElementRef, onDataSelect: EventEmitter, type: "bar", _data: {…}, chart: Chart, …}. Now how should I save the image as .png/.jpeg in local drive?

Comment: Well, since it is based on chart.js, I would imagine you would call the `.toBase64Image()` function to generate a base64 encoded string of the image

Comment: `.toBase64Image()` is not a recognizable property of ElementRef, so its showing compilation error.

Comment: that is a Chart function, so you will need a chart element